# ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I have a model Car in my application. I've added color field. My migration looks like this:

```
class AddColorToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cars, :color, :string
    Car.all.each do |car|
      car.color = "silver"
      car.save
    end
  end
end
```

in my form I've add:

```
= f.input :color
```

and in Car model I've added validation:

```
validates :color, presence: true
```

When I try edit existing Car and change his color to be nil I have the following error:

```
ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

When I disable my validation everything works fine. What's wrong?

Comment: I've restarded a server and it works...

Comment: little tip: If you want to update a bunch of records with the same value(s), I suggest you to use `Car.where(color: 'sylver').update_all(color: 'silver')`

Answer (score 12):

This is all related to the [`transactions`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods) in `Rails` with `PostgreSQL`.

> On some database systems, such as PostgreSQL, database errors inside a
>   transaction cause the entire transaction to become unusable until it’s
>   restarted from the beginning.

You have a transaction aborting that is being caught. This is sometimes caused when adding validations on `ActiveRecord` models. For a reason, you can’t create anything on a table in a transaction once you break the `INSERT` for PostgreSQL. Also, adding validations sometimes breaks the `INSERT`.

**Quick Solution:**
Restart your `Rails` server and your validations will work flawlessly.

Comment: this actually also worked from me.
maybe this is just the short version of "you've made some changes that Rails is not able to completely reload and it needs a reboot."

Comment: Same for me.
I migrated an :integer column to :decimal and had a type mismatch in a transaction that was correctly reported after the restart.